Do you really distinguish the difference between "the shirt's rumpled" and "the shirt's wrinkled" and "the shirt's creased"?
I can not tell the difference between "the shirt's rumpled" and "the shirt's wrinkled" and "the shirt's creased" by just looking at the definitions in dictionaries.
In a casual everyday conversation, Do you really distinguish the difference between "the shirt's rumpled" and "the shirt's wrinkled" and "the shirt's creased"?
I guess the shirt is rumpled and the shirt is wrinkled are quite similar the unwanted folds are created naturally (you created these folds unconcously) but the shirt is creased seems to mean the unwanted folds are created by people (like you actually fold it)

You forgot crumpled!
My take on it:
I would call a garment wrinkled if it hadn't been ironed after being washed - full of small creases.
I would call it creased if it had been placed between other garments in a drawer or suitcase and some unwanted folds had been pressed into it.
I would call it crumpled or rumpled if it had become uneven as a result of being worn, or perhaps being thrown down carelessly.
Note that these are not precise definitions!

I find rumpled the most difficult to describe. What for you is the nature of the "unevenness"? Has the fabric lost its crispness or the shirt its shape? Is it stretched out?  I wouldn't use rumpled of a shirt on someone's back, only of one that has been tossed somewhere.  It's in a little formless heap. But you use the word of the shirt while it is being worn?

@TimR - I was thinking of something like a shirt being partly pulled above the waistband  when the wearer stretches their arms upwards, then collapsing into folds when they sit down. But it could also describe the garment after it is taken off.

Do you say "Your blouse is rucked up in the back"? If so, is  "rumpled" a synonym?

@TimR - Yes, I might. I think of 'rumple' mainly in the context of 'rumpling someone's hair', but it could be a synonym of 'crumple'.

First, no, creases aren’t necessarily intentional.
To call something creased often conveys that the thing bears a single crease. And creases are sharper, more pronounced than are wrinkles. Also, the word crease is usually used for features that are more nearly straight, whereas wrinkle can mean a feature that is more irregularly shaped.
Rumpled suggests that the cause of the non-smoothness is the surface’s having been laid or sat on, whereas a wrinkle can result from, say, an act of crumpling.
